# User.IsInRole() fails when in multiple roles retrieved from Identity Server 4 token

Tags: authorization, identityserver4, roles, claims

If there is a single role in the token, User.IsInRole() works
[image: Claim working (single)]

However, if there are multiple roles, then it does not
[image: Roles failing]

Here is how the roles are added (seems the same as lots of other posts online)
[image: code adding roles to context.issueClaims]

Here is how the roles are decoded from the claims

[image: Option Claim Actions]

This just seems to work for people, and I've read they get the roles back as an array like I get, but it works. So, I assume there is something in the configuration about getting the roles, but I'm out of ideas and hope the great community of SO can help!

***UPDATE 1***

I amended the line
`options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey( "role", "role", "role" );`
to
`options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey( "role", "role" );`

and now my claims look like:

[image: Roles split into individual items]

so the roles are now split from the array, but the IsInRole() still fails to find Administrator (and the others)

Comment: remove `.MapUniqueJsonKey`, and `RoleClaimType = ` in the OIDC auth config. Use the default values, they work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately removing both or just MapUniqueKey results in 0 roles appearing in the permissions test page.

Comment: When you paste the token in https://jwt.io, you can see a role array, right?

Comment: Indeed - "role": [
    "InstitutionalAdmin",
    "IDS_Admin",
    "Administrator"
  ], a single role seems to be OK, just multiple

Comment: Ok, export all claims (`User.Claims.Select(c => new { c.Type, c.Value }).ToList()`), there should be multiple role claims of type `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`. Then see if it matches identity's `RoleClaimType` (`User.Identities.First().RoleClaimType`). Make sure you're using the default settings, (remove the overrides like I've mentioned above)

Comment: Starting to understand more what is happening. My role claim is just "role" not the MSFT one. from the screenshot above, you can see how the roles are added to the claim. Also, the permissions page shows the list of claims. If i remove some variant of //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey( "role", "role" ); then I get no roles in the claims list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236007/discussion-between-simon-and-abdusco).

Answer (score 3):

The right combination is:

Since the default roleClaimType is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` this needs to match what the claim is actually being sent as. In my case, this is just "role". Therefore

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    RoleClaimType = "role",
    NameClaimType = "name"
};
```

is needed to specify that "role" is the claim to look for. However, that was not sufficient on it's own. The role claims were not being added to the list of claims. This line of code was required:

`options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey( "role", "role" );`

and this says for the "role" claim type (param 1) look in the json token and find a json key of "role" (param 2). This is sufficient to now get the roles into the claims list for the user.

In the claims list which I printed on my /permissions page i see

```
role InstitutionalAdmin
role IDS_Admin
role Administrator
```

printed out, there are now the three claims listed (not in an array)

and the IsInRole is now behaving too:

```
Administrator
True
Attendee
False
InstitutionalAdmin
True
ModuleUserAdmin
False
IDS_Admin
True
```

This is a subset of what was printed out, but the three claim roles are now being set as True in the IsInRole call. Not sure exactly what differs from Update1 but, subject to further testing, it looks good now.

My final points are to firstly thank https://stackoverflow.com/users/5298150/abdusco for engaging and prompting me to look and understand what each param meant. Secondly, I always believe that in pasting code you find on the web is fine, and justified (why reinvent the wheel), BUT please take the time to fully understand what it does and why it is there.

Comment: Interesting discussion, just passed this way too. So, `options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey` causes to put all roles to the single claim as array, while `options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey` rolls out all roles to a few separate claims (that is required). On the top, `NameClaimType = "role"` needs to bind separate roles to the internal .Net Core role system, so functions like User.IsInRole() can work.